# How to keep an input to represent a variable instead of a str by default

Tags: python

I'm a beginner in python, and I'm trying to make a program that can refer to a single dictionary out of a couple of dictionaries, and then access its contents. Like this:

```
dict1 = {'Joe':'three', 'Bob':'nine'}
dict2 = {'Jill':'apple', 'Karen':'blanket'}
a = input('Type in the dict you would like to access: ')
```

and then hopefully a could == dict1 or dict2, and then I could continue with the rest of my operations

I wanted 'a' to be == to dict1 if that's what the user inputs, so I could later search a like (a[key]), and do other operations with it.

However, it defaults to str, and I don't know how to get the input to assign the dictionary dict1 to variable a instead of the string 'dict1'. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hint: Make a dict of dicts, then you can reference by key.

Comment: Tip: Whenever you have more than one variable that's basically the same, differentiated only a number at the end, then you usually need some kind of structure, like an array or dict instead. Here you could use `{ 'dict1': ..., ... }` or `[ { ... }, { ... } ]` much the same, interpreting `dict1` as `dicts[0]`.

Comment: you might also try `globals()[a]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the use of nested dictionaries.

```
dicts = {
    "dict1":{'Joe':'three', 'Bob':'nine'},
    "dict2":{'Jill':'apple', 'Karen':'blanket'},
}

a = input('Type in the dict you would like to access: ')

chosen_dict = dicts.get(a)

print(chosen_dict)
```